# Hreflang tags on both English and German versions of a website?

Tags: hreflang

I'm working on a multi-language website, English and German. I'm using the `hreflang` tags below on the German website.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.website.com/de">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.website.com/en" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.website.com/de" hreflang="de" />
```

Is it necessary to do the same on the English website? Currently the English website isn't using `hreflang` tags

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... Yes.

Great explanation by Ahrefs here
https://ahrefs.com/blog/hreflang-tags/